# What is my Sago Palm releasing into the air and is it seasonal?

Tags: houseplants

I just bought a small Sago Palm and it's been sitting in my room for the last week. It doesn't have a flower spike, so I assume it's not releasing spores. But it gives off a slight musky smell, and my allergies have been going haywire. If it's not spores, what could it be releasing? And is it likely to be seasonal, or permanent?

[image]

Comment: Have you been diagnosed with any allergies? If so, what plant allergies do you have? Have you had houseplants in that same space before, without any problems?

Comment: I've only previously been diagnosed with an allergy to cypress pollen. But that was specifically testing common allergens in my hometown and didn't consider exotic things. Never had any issue with houseplants before.

Answer (score 2):

I can't dig into the picture, but it looks like the plant is showing some stress. Look at the coloration in the circled area on top: Was it like that when you bought it? And the thing at the base? Is it rot, or a different color of the potting soil? The base is more troubling than the leaves. Make sure there is no standing water above the drainage holes of the inner pot.
[image]

Comment: I think the circle in the base is the part where it was separated from the mother plant. It's definitely under stress, as it's only just been transplanted.

Answer (score 1):

thornate,it could be mold or mildew. I suggest you may have 'old' water sitting in the bottom of that decorative pot. Air can't circulate around the pot, and the water can't evaporate, thus, the 'musky' odor. Get a nice big colorful dinner plate and use it as a drainage dish. Beautiful palm.!